# Field expressions values are not shown for guest users in SEO Title of B2B Commerce store page

Tags: b2b-commerce, experience-builder-page, seo

I'm using field expressions in the SEO Title on the Product Detail page of B2B Commerce store. It works as expected when the user is logged in, but for guest users field expressions values are not visible in the title of the page, even though Product object and fields access is provided for Guest User Profile.

[image: SEO Title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated configuration in Prod to Enabled
Give Guest Users Access to Public Chatter API requests

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the selected answer works for Aura website. For LWR, the name of the setting would be "Allow guest users to access public APIs" ([documentation reference](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_guest_users_access_rename.htm&release=238&type=5)). In both cases, the setting is found in Workspaces -> Administration -> Preferences.